# iptables - what does LOCALOUTPUT action do?

Tags: iptables

Can anyone please tell me what does this rule do? 
Specifically I want to know what `LOCALOUTPUT` action means?

```
root@host123 [/tmp]# /sbin/iptables -L OUTPUT -n --line-number -v | grep 266
266      681K      722M      LOCALOUTPUT      all      --      *      !lo      0.0.0.0/0      0.0.0.0/0
root@host123 [/tmp]#
```

Answer (score 1):

All traffic, not going to interface `lo`, will jump to the chain `LOCALOUTPUT`. What's in LOCALOUTPUT will be shown by `iptables -L LOCALOUTPUT`